# Do I need to give my apple app same name as the provisioning file?

Tags: file, ipad, provisioning

I am a newbie in apple app development. And I work for my professor so the university pays for the provisioning profile. Here I have several questions about it:

1. If the app ID is "*.edu.university.lab.HelloWorld", and its name is "HelloWorld", to run my app on the iPad, do I have to give my app exactly the same name (that is HelloWorld) as the provisioning file's name?
2. If the above is true, I have to build and test my app in other programs before running it in real iPad. How can I copy the entire program by just changing the name to HellowWorld?

Thanks a lot!

Dora

Answer (score 0):

App ID can include wild card, for example edu.university.* when you are testing on devices.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I check whether it includes the wild card or not?

Answer (score 0):

An app id can be whatever you like, so long as it follows `com.yourdomain.yourappname`. Your app does not need to be called the same thing as the `yourappname` portion of your bundle id. If `yourappname` is set to `*`, then it is said to be a `wildcard`.

When you create a distribution profile, you include what the bundle id will be. The bundle ID must match that. Everything else can be what you want.